# Optimizing query in MySQL5.6

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have an INNODB table `levels`:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | int(9)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| level_name         | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| user_id            | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| user_name          | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rating             | decimal(5,4) | NO   |     | 0.0000  |       |
| votes              | int(5)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| plays              | int(5)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| date_published     | date         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| user_comment       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| playable_character | int(2)       | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| is_featured        | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

There are ~4 million rows. Because of the front-end functionality, I need to query this table with a variety of filters and sorts. They are on `playable_character`, `rating`, `plays`, and `date_published`. The `date_published` can be filtered to show by the last day, week, month, or anytime(last 3 years). There's also paging. So, depending on the user choices, the queries can look, for example, like one of these:

```
SELECT * FROM levels
WHERE playable_character = 0 AND
    date_published BETWEEN date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR) AND now()
ORDER BY date_published DESC
LIMIT 0, 1000;

SELECT * FROM levels
WHERE playable_character = 4 AND
    date_published BETWEEN date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND now()
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 4000, 1000;

SELECT * FROM levels
WHERE playable_character = 5 AND
    date_published BETWEEN date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND now()
ORDER BY plays DESC
LIMIT 1000, 1000;
```

I started out with an index `idx_date_char(date_published, playable_character)` that works *great* on the first example query here -- basically anything that's ordering by `date_published`. Using EXPLAIN, I get 'using index condition', which is good. I think I understand why the index works, since the same two indexed columns exist in the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses.

My problem is with queries that ORDER by `plays` or `rating`. I understand I'm introducing a third column, but for the life of me I can't get an index that works well, despite trying just about every variation I could think of: composite indexes of all three or four in every order, and so on. Maybe the query could be written differently?

I should add that `rating` and `plays` are always queried as `DESC`. Only `date_published` may be either `DESC` or `ASC`.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Did you try covering index , smth like `ON (date_sub ASC, playable_character ASC, rating DESC) ` ? Note , first columns are in ascending order, the last one in descending since your query has `ORDER BY rating DESC` + limit...

Comment: For the first query, an index on `(playable_character, date_published)` would be even better. For the 2nd and 3rd, it's more complex and they are not easily optimized.

Comment: @ypercube - I could have sworn that was slower yesterday and was giving me a 'where' in the EXPLAIN extra column. But you're right, I just compared them now and it is faster (and is 'Using index condition').

Comment: Actually, it may perform slower with that index, depending on the table structure (is it MyISAM or InnoDB? What is the primary key?) and usage and because you have `SELECT *`. Only if you have just `SELECT date_published` in the 1st query, the `(playable_character, date_published)` is undoubtly better.

Comment: @a1ex07 - would it be possible to see an example of the full query you're suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you would make good use of data sorted in this way for each of the queries:

1. playable_character, date_published
2. playable_character, date_published, rating
3. playable_character, date_published, plays

Bear in mind that the data you need sorted in the first query happens to be a subset of the data the second and third query needs, so we can get rid of it.

Also note that adding `DESC` or `ASC` to an index is syntactically correct but doesn't actually change anything as that feature is not currently supported (it is expected to be supported in the future so that is why it is there). All indexes are stored in ascending order. More information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).

So these are the indexes that you should create:

```
ALTER TABLE levels ADD INDEX (playable_character, date_published, rating)
ALTER TABLE levels ADD INDEX (playable_character, date_published, plays)
```

That should make the 3 queries up there run faster than Forrest Gump.

Comment: Thanks. Something rather interesting is going on. First, the two indexes do work well, however there is a situation where they don't. Consider this: `SELECT count(*) FROM levels WHERE playable_character = 0; /*'1724061'*/
SELECT count(*) FROM levels WHERE playable_character = 10; /*'6718'*/` When the date_published is 3 years it's basically every record. In EXPLAIN, 'using where' pops up when the rows (in EXPLAIN) are somewhere around 700,000, and performance on the query drops in the extreme. Do you know what's happening?

Comment: The more `unique` an index is the faster the data would be fetched. If you have many hundreds of thousands records that match the query (in the `where` clause) then you will have to sort hundreds of thousands. There isn't much to do in those cases as that is how data is distributed. The next step should increasing resources such as `read_rnd_buffer_size` and `sort_buffer_size`. Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) for information about them. Or ask a question in http://dba.stackexchange.com . They can help you more :)

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho read_rnd_buffer_size and sort_buffer_size settings can be very dangerous settings to adjust..Hal50000 is now asking here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51771/how-to-optimize-indexes-on-mysql-query-with-various-sorts about the settings..

Comment: @RaymondNijland `Dangerous` is a scary word :) They should be properly configured and that is why I derived him to the other stackexchange site in order to follow their advice. As a side note, I see the question you linked is not asking about those settings but rather is basically asking the same question as here (with modifications to the index that I actually didn't suggest, as ypercube mentioned in a comment). I guess I did my part :)

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho you should be scared :-).. i think filesort is the problem.. if the number off records is unknown to be sorted filesort will ask the storage engine an estimate (yes that matches the where) and is using this value to reserve memory and yes this should be memory for ~700.000 records.. because limit is executed after the filesort (quicksort).. get an explainment from filesort.cc off the MySQL sourcecode and googling on "avoid filesort" i found this also  -> https://blogs.oracle.com/realneel/entry/improving_filesort_performance_in_mysql

Answer (score 1):

The columns used in your where clause AND order by should be part of the index.  I would have an index on

```
( playable_character, date_published DESC, rating DESC, plays DESC )
```

The reason I would put the playable character FIRST is you want that ID primary, then all those dates within question.  The rating and plays are just along for the ride for assisting the ORDER BY clause).

Think of the index like this.  If you have it ordered by Date_Published, then Playable_Character, think of a room of boxes.  Each box has a date.. Within that box for a given date, you have them in order of character.  So, you have 3 years worth of data to go through, you have to open all boxes for the last 3 years and find the character you are looking for.

Now, think of it like this.  Each box is by character, and within that, all their dates are pre-sorted.  So, you go to one box, open it... Move to the date in question and grab the records from X-Y range you want.  Now, you can apply a simple order by of those records.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation is helpful in understanding the nature of the index and the query.

Answer (score 1):

When your query includes a range predicate like `BETWEEN`, the order of columns in your index is important.

- First, include one or more columns referenced by *equality* predicates.
- Next, include one column referenced by a *range* predicate.
- Any further columns in the index after the column referenced by a range predicate cannot be used for other range predicates or for sorting.
- If you have no range predicate, you can add a column for sort order.

So your first query can benefit from an index on `(playable_character, date_published)`.  The sorting should be a no-op because the optimizer will just fetch rows in the index order.

The second and third queries are bound to do a filesort, because you have a range predicate and then you're sorting by a different column. If you had had only equality predicates, you would be able to use the third column to avoid the filesort, but that doesn't work when you have a range predicate.

The best you can hope for is that the conditions reduce the size of the result set so that it can sort in memory without doing too many [sort merge passes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Sort_merge_passes). You can help this by increasing [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size), but be careful not to increase it too much, because it's allocated per thread.

The `ASC`/`DESC` keywords in index definitions makes no difference in MySQL.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html:

> These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order.